# JEST Mongoose POST test failing - toBeCalledWith()

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jestjs, tdd

I'm trying to learn JEST by implementing it on my current OKR API - But I can't seem to get this POST request validation working... I'm wondering if any of you amazing folks can assist. I'm brand new to this and not exactly clear on strategies to debug JEST issues. appreciate all and any help :)

JEST Code:

```js
    const objectiveController = require('../../controller/objectives-controller');
    const ObjectiveModel = require('../../Models/Objectives')
    const httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http')
    const newObjective = require('../mock/objectiveMockData.json')

    ObjectiveModel.create = jest.fn()
    let req, res, next;
    beforeEach(() => {
        req = httpMocks.createRequest();
        res = httpMocks.createResponse();
        next = null

    })

 describe('objectiveController.postObjective', () => {
    it('Should have a post function', () => {
        expect(typeof objectiveController.postObjective).toBe('function')
    })
    it('Should call ObjectiveModel.create', () => {
        req.body = newObjective
        ObjectiveModel.create(req, res, next);
        expect(ObjectiveModel.create).toBeCalledWith(req.body);
    })
})
```

Here is the controller logic:

```js
exports.postObjective = async (req,res,next) => {
    req.body.user = req.user.id

    try {
        const objective = await Objectives.create(req.body)
        res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            data: objective
    })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
            success: false
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the mock JSON:

```json
{
    "name": "____MOCK POST REQUEST DATA TITLE",
    "description": "___MOCK POST REQUEST DATA DESCRIPTION",
    "atRisk": false,
    "user": "60e2f4d5a85e1c5ba5fc995e"
}
```

And, here is the Mongoose Model:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const slugify = require('slugify')
const chalk = require('chalk')


const ObjectiveSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: [true, 'Please add a name'],
          unique: true,
          trim: true,
          maxlength: [75, 'Name can not be more than 75 characters']
        },
        slug: String,
        description: {
          type: String,
          required: [true, 'Please add a description'],
          maxlength: [500, 'Description can not be more than 500 characters']
        },
        atRisk: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
        },
        user: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User',
          required: false
        }
      },
      {
        toJSON: { virtuals: true },
        toObject: { virtuals: true }
      }
)


// cascading delete - if we delete the objective - we should delete the 
ObjectiveSchema.pre('remove', async function(next) {
  console.log(`courses being removed from objective: ${this._id}`)
  await this.model('KeyResult').deleteMany({
    objective: this._id
  })
})

//? Create a SLUG pre-save
ObjectiveSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.slug = slugify(this.name, {
      lower: true,
    })
    next()
  })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Objectives', ObjectiveSchema);
```

Here is the extreamly long output from running the test

```sh
 FAIL  tests/unit/objective.controller.test.js
  objectiveController.deleteObjective
    ✓ Should have a delete function (2 ms)
  objectiveController.getObjectives
    ✓ Should be a get function
  objectiveController.postObjective
    ✓ Should have a post function (1 ms)
    ✕ Should call ObjectiveModel.create (6 ms)
  objectiveController.getSingleObjective
    ✓ Should have a get function
  objectiveController.updateObjective
    ✓ Should have a put function (1 ms)

  ● objectiveController.postObjective › Should call ObjectiveModel.create

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

    - Expected
    + Received

    - Object {
    + EventEmitter {
    +   "_addBody": [Function anonymous],
    +   "_events": Object {},
    +   "_eventsCount": 0,
    +   "_maxListeners": undefined,
    +   "_setBaseUrl": [Function anonymous],
    +   "_setBody": [Function anonymous],
    +   "_setCookiesVariable": [Function anonymous],
    +   "_setFilesVariable": [Function anonymous],
    +   "_setHeadersVariable": [Function anonymous],
    +   "_setMethod": [Function anonymous],
    +   "_setOriginalUrl": [Function anonymous],
    +   "_setParameter": [Function anonymous],
    +   "_setSessionVariable": [Function anonymous],
    +   "_setSignedCookiesVariable": [Function anonymous],
    +   "_setURL": [Function anonymous],
    +   "accepts": [Function anonymous],
    +   "acceptsCharsets": [Function anonymous],
    +   "acceptsEncodings": [Function anonymous],
    +   "acceptsLanguages": [Function anonymous],
    +   "baseUrl": "",
    +   "body": Object {
          "atRisk": false,
          "description": "___MOCK POST REQUEST DATA DESCRIPTION",
          "name": "____MOCK POST REQUEST DATA TITLE",
          "user": "60e2f4d5a85e1c5ba5fc995e",
    +   },
    +   "cookies": Object {},
    +   "files": Object {},
    +   "get": [Function anonymous],
    +   "header": [Function anonymous],
    +   "headers": Object {},
    +   "hostname": "",
    +   "is": [Function anonymous],
    +   "method": "GET",
    +   "originalUrl": "",
    +   "param": [Function anonymous],
    +   "params": Object {},
    +   "path": "",
    +   "query": Object {},
    +   "range": [Function anonymous],
    +   "send": [Function anonymous],
    +   "socket": Object {},
    +   "subdomains": Array [],
    +   "url": "",
    +   Symbol(kCapture): false,
      },
    + {"_getBuffer": [Function anonymous], "_getChunks": [Function anonymous], "_getData": [Function anonymous], "_getHeaders": [Function anonymous], "_getJSONData": [Function anonymous], "_getLocals": [Function anonymous], "_getRedirectUrl": [Function anonymous], "_getRenderData": [Function anonymous], "_getRenderView": [Function anonymous], "_getStatusCode": [Function anonymous], "_getStatusMessage": [Function anonymous], "_headers": {}, "_isDataLengthValid": [Function anonymous], "_isEndCalled": [Function anonymous], "_isJSON": [Function anonymous], "_isUTF8": [Function anonymous], "append": [Function append], "clearCookie": [Function anonymous], "contentType": [Function anonymous], "cookie": [Function anonymous], "cookies": {}, "destroy": [Function anonymous], "destroySoon": [Function anonymous], "end": [Function anonymous], "finished": false, "format": [Function anonymous], "get": [Function anonymous], "getEncoding": [Function anonymous], "getHeader": [Function anonymous], "getHeaderNames": [Function anonymous], "getHeaders": [Function anonymous], "hasHeader": [Function anonymous], "header": [Function header], "headersSent": false, "json": [Function anonymous], "jsonp": [Function anonymous], "locals": {}, "location": [Function anonymous], "redirect": [Function anonymous], "removeHeader": [Function anonymous], "render": [Function anonymous], "send": [Function anonymous], "sendStatus": [Function sendStatus], "set": [Function header], "setEncoding": [Function anonymous], "setHeader": [Function anonymous], "status": [Function anonymous], "statusCode": 200, "statusMessage": "OK", "type": [Function anonymous], "vary": [Function anonymous], "writableEnded": false, "writableFinished": false, "write": [Function anonymous], "writeHead": [Function anonymous]},
    + null,

    Number of calls: 1

      45 |         req.body = newObjective
      46 |         ObjectiveModel.create(req, res, next);
    > 47 |         expect(ObjectiveModel.create).toBeCalledWith(req.body);
         |                                       ^
      48 |     })
      49 |     it('Should return a 201', () => {
      50 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/objective.controller.test.js:47:39)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 6 passed, 7 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.466 s, estimated 2 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: You need to elaborate on the issue that you are experiencing. Write now you just have a bunch of code, and no one wants to sift through your code and find the problems, and teach you about the problems. Its your responsibility to define the issue you are having, and you didn't do that, which means there  is not enough info here to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the controller method `postObjective`.

```js
    it('Should call ObjectiveModel.create', async () => {
        req.body = newObjective;
    
        await objectiveController.postObjective(req, res, next);

        expect(ObjectiveModel.create).toBeCalledWith(req.body);
    })
```

I think you also need to mock the `'../../Models/Objectives'` module,
so i think you need to put it before the tests:
`jest.mock('../../Models/Objectives')`

and remove the `ObjectiveModel.create = jest.fn()` line

Comment: Thanks so much! Can’t believe I missed that but I really appreciate the swift answer.

Comment: Glad to help :)